# Change text color in Node.js [DISCORD]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to change the color of the text displayed by the bot on Discord, but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: @vibhor1997a — Discord is not the console.

Comment: Yes i know that. I just want to change the text color displayed by bot on Discord chat. But for that, i need the code

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly change the color of text. Not that I know of anyway. However, you can use code blocks with a language tag to color text in accordance to the language.

https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-